# Problema con el plugin de greenDAO jar

Tags: android, android-studio, plugin, greendao

Estoy obteniendo este mensaje desde android studio al intentar insertar el plugin de greendao desde el disco "Fail to load plugin descriptor from file greendao-gradle-plugin-3.2.2.jar", he investigado acerca del error y encontré que le falta el plugin.xml, necesito ese archivo o al menos el código que lleve dentro para insertar el plugin en el android studio, en caso de conocer otra solución o el jar correcto mejor.Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Leo, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. En cuanto a tu pregunta para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad debe estar realizada en base al documento [ask], te recomiendo añadir más detalles.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya debes tener en algún lugar ese texto solo para copiar y pegar Jajaj